# Is there a good way of converting an uint8_t array into a single float value that doesn't involve a loop?

Tags: c, parsing, esp-idf, nmea

Is there a better way of converting an uint8_t array into a single float value?

I am extremely new at using this.
I am currently using a ESP32-S3-WROOM-1 to take UART data from a NEO-6M GPS.
IDE: Visual Studio Code

I *think* my code (which I attached below the c and h file) should take the UART data and place it into an array. For time I can just set it two by two, but for longer values like Latitude and Longitude, I will have to have the code add and multiply each other until it reaches the decimal point, then add the rest of the values later.

Basically, going byte by byte.

```
char* Post_Time_String = strstr(String_Input, ",");
    F_Extract_Until_Comma(Post_Time_String, Lat_Val);
    for(int itr=0; itr<sizeof(Lat_Val),itr++)
    {
        if(Lat_Val[itr] != ".")
        {
            gps_info->GPS_POSITION->latitude = (10 * gps_info->GPS_POSITION->latitude) + Lat_Val[itr];
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to find a better way of doing this, because I get the feeling that this is very inefficient and slow. If I can get the above like a string, then I can use strof() I think?

For reference the header and main files I am currently working on. WIP and definitely has issues that I can't find yet.
NMEA_PARSE_CODE.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <NMEA_PARSE_CODE.h>

void F_FIND_COMMA(char *String_Input, char* String_Output)
{
    char *String_Output = strstr(String_Input, ",");

    return String_Output;
}

void F_Extract_Until_Comma(char *String_Input, uint8_t* Extracted_Output[])
{
    uint8_t String_Length = strlen(String_Input);
    uint8_t* F_Buffer[20] = {NULL};
    char* comma_parse_string = F_FIND_COMMA(String_Input); //Get string after comma
    //Find comma and extract data until next comma

    uint8_t comma_parse_string_length = strlen(comma_parse_string); //Get length of string after comma

    for (uint8_t itr = 0; itr < comma_parse_string_length, itr++)
    {
        if(comma_parse_string[itr] == ",")
        {
            break;
        }
        F_Buffer[itr] = comma_parse_string[itr];
        Extracted_Output[itr] = comma_parse_string[itr];
        

    }

}

void F_U8_to_F(uint8_t Input_val, uint8_t pos, float* Output)
{
    float OutputHold;
    OutputHold = 10*Input_val[pos];
    OutputHold = OutputHold + Input_val[pos+1];
    Output = OutputHold;
}

void F_NMEA_TIME_CONVERT(uint8_t Input_Val, NMEA_GPS gps_info)
{
    F_U8_to_F(timeval, 0, gps_info->GPS_TIME->nmea_hours);
    F_U8_to_F(timeval, 2, gps_info->GPS_TIME->nmea_minutes);
    F_U8_to_F(timeval, 4, gps_info->GPS_TIME->nmea_seconds);
}


void F_GGA_Parse(uint8_t* String_Input, NMEA_GPS gps_info)
{
    //TIME, Lat, N/S, Long, E/W, Fix, Sat#, HDOP, Alt, unit, Geoid, unit,  .........
    strof();
    uint8_t time_value[12], Lat_Val[12]; //obtain from String_Input and to convert into float value
    F_Extract_Until_Comma(String_Input, time_value);
    F_NMEA_TIME_CONVERT(time_value, gps_info)

    //time end
    char* Post_Time_String = strstr(String_Input, ",");
    F_Extract_Until_Comma(Post_Time_String, Lat_Val);
    for(int itr=0; itr<sizeof(Lat_Val),itr++)
    {
        if(Lat_Val[itr] != ".")
        {
            gps_info->GPS_POSITION->latitude = (10 * gps_info->GPS_POSITION->latitude) + Lat_Val[itr];
        }
    }
    F_U8_to_F(Lat_Val,0,gps_info);


}


char F_Extract_GPS_Data(char * raw_string_input, NMEA_GPS* gps_info)
{
    char* GPS_ID_FOUND = strstr(raw_string_input, "$GP");
    uint8_t Comma_Rounds = 0;

    if(NULL == GPS_ID_FOUND)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strstr(GPS_ID_FOUND, "GGA"))
        {
            gps_info->GPS_TYPE = GGA;
            gps_info->GGA_Flag = YES;
            Comma_Rounds = 14;
        }
        else if(strstr(GPS_ID_FOUND,"RMC"))
        {
            gps_info->GPS_TYPE = RMC;
            gps_info->RMC_Flag = YES;
            Comma_Rounds = 11;
        }
        else if(strstr(GPS_ID_FOUND,"VTG"))
        {
            gps_info->GPS_TYPE = VTG;
            gps_info->VTG_Flag = YES;
            Comma_Rounds = 9;
        }

        if(gps_info->GPS_TYPE == 1)
        {
            F_GGA_Parse(GPS_ID_FOUND, gps_info);
        }


        // if(GPS_ID_FOUND[0])
    }
}
```

NMEA_PARSE_CODE.h

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef enum
{
    NO=0,
    YES=1
} NMEA_ID_GGA;

typedef enum
{
    NO=0,
    YES=1
} NMEA_ID_RMC;

typedef enum
{
    NO=0,
    YES=1
} NMEA_ID_VTG;

typedef enum 
{
    GGA=1,
    RMC,
    VTG

} NMEA_ID;

typedef struct
{
    float nmea_hours;
    float nmea_minutes;
    float nmea_seconds;
    float nmea_thousands;
} NMEA_UTC_TIME;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t nmea_year;
    uint8_t nmea_month;
    uint8_t nmea_day;
} NMEA_DATE;

typedef struct
{
    float longitude;
    float latitude;
} NMEA_POSITION;

typedef struct
{
    char NORTHSOUTH;
    char EASTWEST;
    float course; //In degrees
    float knot_speed; //In knots
    float meter_speed; //In meters per second
} NMEA_VELOCITY;

typedef struct
{
    NMEA_ID GPS_TYPE;
    NMEA_ID_GGA GGA_Flag;
    NMEA_ID_RMC RMC_Flag;
    NMEA_ID_VTG VTG_Flag;
    NMEA_UTC_TIME GPS_TIME;
    NMEA_DATE GPS_DATE;
    NMEA_POSITION GPS_POSITION;
    NMEA_VELOCITY GPS_VELOCITY;

} NMEA_GPS;

typedef struct
{
    NMEA_ID ID;
    NMEA_UTC_TIME TIME;

} NMEA_GGA;
```

Going byte by byte, multiply the existing float value by 10 before adding the new byte. Repeat until end of length is reached. The code compiles somehow in Visual Studio Code, but that isn't saying much. VSC isn't showing me any errors either.

Comment: Please describe your input format. uint8_t array, raw binary, string, what? It can't be all at once.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] – which means, too, that the code should at least compile (unless your question is explicitly about why the code doesn't do so) – a void function trying to return something *won't* compile...

Comment: Avoid all capital letter function names – such identifiers usually refer to *macros*. Currently most common convention is camel case: `theNameOfSomeFunction` with initial small letter (though MS dominated environments prefer initial capital letter, thus Pascal case).

Comment: I am puzzled by what you try to achieve. Please provide sample contents of the uint8_t array, along with the expected resulting float values.

Comment: Did I just overlook the declaration of `Lat_Val` between all those irrelevant structs or is it indeed missing? If the latter, hopefully it is an *array* of sufficient size, otherwise you likely are in trouble.

Comment: Are the values in the input array *binary* values or textual representation? If the latter (seems so as you multiply by 10) you won't get desired results, you'll then need to add `Lat_Val[itr] - '0'` instead.

Comment: Recommend to use `double` instead of `float` – there's just no reason for dropping precision if input format is text anyway.

Comment: The more I read the code again and again the more it appears just nonsense to me (e.g. why are you calling `strtof` without arguments?) – sorry if that sounds a bit harsh. Assuming you have a string containing a series of floating point values separated by comma then you can simply do: `char const* input = ...; for(;;) { char* end; double value = strtod(input, &end); if(end == input) { /* parsing failure -> some appropriate error handling} if(*end && *end != ',') { /* yet another parsing error? */ } /* handle the value */ if(*end == 0) { /* last value, we're done... */ break; } input = end; }`

Comment: Now handling parsing errors depends on what's meaningful to you, at very least you should exit from the loop, maybe by returning an error code or by throwing an exception. Handling the parsed value might comprise adding it to a `std::vector`, or calling some callback function. If you want to handle one single value at a time then the `double` variable might be an output paremeter (`double& value`) and you might return a pointer to the first unparsed character (the one after the comma), maybe returning null on error (or inverse). You wouldn't need the loop then, of course.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thank you for everything and sorry about all the things I did. I am very much not used to coding, and I am trying to convert the draft of the company's concept notes for a DTG into code format because everyone else who is computer literate is gone.

Comment: @JohnSmith *'sorry for [...]'* – well, there's really no reason for excusing – you're here because you are in trouble, we are here to help you out ;) Sometimes it happens that some advice might sound a bit harsh, but even if, intent usually is a good one...

Answer (score 3):

In answer to the question you asked, no, there is not a way of converting a string like `42.23234` to a `float` that does not involve a loop, somewhere.  Moreover, simply "multiply the existing float value by 10 before adding the new byte" is completely insufficient for floating-point values, because it doesn't handle the decimal point or the fractional digits after it.

The simple way to convert a string to a floating-point value (which, incidentally, does not involve any loops in *your* code) is to call a prewritten library function such as `atof`, `strtod`, or `sscanf`.  And using a prewritten library function is highly, highly recommended here, because properly converting floating-point strings is quite a hard problem in general, and it's much better to let someone else do that work.

Here's a simple example:

```
char *p = "42.23234,N,071.34681,E";    /* might be part of a NMEA string */
char *p2;
double lat = strtod(p, &p2);
printf("lat = %f, rest = %s\n", lat, p2);
```

This prints

```
lat = 42.232340, rest = ,N,071.34681,E
```

The way this works is that `strtod` converts the first part of the string you give it to a `double`, then returns you (via a "reference" pointer parameter) a pointer to the rest of the string, that it didn't convert, because it ran into a non-numeric character, in this case the first comma.

[Beware, though, that in NMEA, 42.23234 does *not* mean 42.23234 degrees.  It's actually 42 degrees, 23.234 minutes, which works out to 42.3872333 degrees.  So it turns out you're not going to be able to use a straightforward call to `strtod` to get your latitudes and longitudes, after all.]

Although not the question you asked, the rest of your code has many, many problems beyond that of converting floating-point strings.  I recommend starting with a smaller, simpler problem.  Or if you need to parse NMEA strings today, see if you can find some prewritten code that fits your needs — there's gobs and gobs of it out there.

If you do want to write your own NMEA parser, I recommend treating the problem as two completely separate parts:

1. Break a sentence up into comma-separated fields
2. Handle each field separately, depending on the particular string you're parsing ($GPGGA, $GPVTG, $GPZDA, etc.)

But trying to move along the string one character at a time, simultaneously converting field contents and looking for commas, tends to lead to an unholy mess.

One decent way to break a string up into comma-separated fields is to use the library function `strtok`.

Miscellaneous other notes:

1. Type `float` does not have enough precision for global latitudes and longitudes.  Use `double`.  (Actually, a fine general rule is that type `float` doesn't really have enough precision for anything, so you should *always* use `double`.)
2. If you have a function `void F_U8_to_F(uint8_t Input_val, uint8_t pos, float* Output)` that's supposed to return a value via the reference parameter `Output`, you need to assign that using `*Output = OutputHold;`.  (Your compiler should have warned you about this.)
3. When you're calling that function `F_U8_to_F` that's supposed to return a value via a reference parameter, you need to pass a pointer to the value you want to fill in: `F_U8_to_F(timeval, 2, &gps_info->GPS_TIME->nmea_minutes);`
4. I recommend using `int` (not `float`) for `nmea_hours` and `nmea_minutes`.  (And if you're going to carry `nmea_thousands` separately, you don't need a `float` for it or for `nmea_seconds`, either.)  But depending on the needs of the rest of the program, you might find it more useful to convert to a more computation-friendly time format, not separate hours, minutes, and seconds fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. For background context, the company I am working for has assigned me to make a DTG. I cannot ask anyone because no one has any idea how to code. I do not know what happened to all the company's coders and no one I asks knows either.

Comment: My personal recommendation in respect to more friendly format is using fixed point comma arithmetic (in the form of using sub-precision units; in given case: converting hours and minutes all just into minutes or even seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, ..., if that precision is needed) – only on outputting to the user convert back, which should for hours and minutes simply comprise a div/mod operation by 60. Recommending, too, fixed-width types, possibly `int64_t` to be on the safe side, though 32 bit might be fine, depending on precision required.

Comment: *'Beware, though'* – in respect to my previous comment: Precision is always the same (thus 'milli-minutes')? That would mean we could just parse two integers, multiply the first by 60000 and add both to get a single integral value. If precision can differ we might need to take the number of digits into account (calculate into minutes, 'deci-minutes', 'centi-minutes', ...) and multiply/divide to receive the desired final precision...

Answer (score 0):

*Extending* on [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340354/1312382), profiting from the information about `NMEA` format given there:

I personally recommend dropping floating point *entirely* and instead fall back to fixed-comma-arithmetic – meaning that you do not represent full degrees, but some appropriate sub-precision. This makes all internal handling much easier and avoids any potential rounding issues (where you might not get back exactly the same value as you have been reading before).

In given case it appears meaningful to me to use the same sub-precision as NMEA:

> Beware, though, that in NMEA, 42.23234 does not mean 42.23234 degrees. It's actually 42 degrees, 23.234 minutes, which works out to 42.3872333 degrees.
>
> [Steve Summit]

If this precision is fix (always thousands of minutes, so 'milli-minutes') *and* trailing zeros are included (the most simple case), then you can simply parse two integers and apply an appropriate factor:

```
char* nmea = ...;
char* end;
signed long degrees = strtol(nmea, &end, 10);
```

Now `*end` should contain a the period. If *not*, then the fractional part is missing and you can just normalise the degrees to the corresponding unit, in case of 'milli-minutes' with 60000.

With fraction available we now can go on:

```
nmea = end + 1; // assuming we're in a function thus have a copy
                // of the pointer anyway
signed long milliMinutes = strtol(nmea, &end, 10);
```

If trailing zeros are *guaranteed* to be included then `end - nmea` should now be equal to 5. If it is not – well, you need to extend:

```
ptrdiff_t length = end - nmea;
for(; length < 5; ++length) // or whatever else desired precision
{
    milliMinutes *= 10;
}
```

This is fine even if the case appears that you have *too many* digits (you'd have chosen a too small precision then). To cover that case as well, you instead need to divide - and we might remember the last digit dropped to determine rounding:

```
int digit = 0;
for(; length > 5; --length)
{
    digit = milliMinutes % 10;
    milliMinutes /= 10;
}
milliMinutes += digit >= 5;
```

Actually no need for surrounding `if`s, the condition within the loop covers the respective inverse cases. Now finally you can combine, but you need to consider that signs of the two numbers might differ:

```
if(degrees < 0)
{
    milliMinutes = -milliMinutes;
}
milliMinutes += degrees + 60000;
```

or, if you prefer branchless:

```
milliMinutes
    = degrees * 60000
    + milliMinutes * (degrees >= 0)
    - milliMinutes * (degrees < 0);
```

Now you have a single integral value and none of the issues with floating point - perfect for internal handling.

The sole disadvantage: When outputting to the user by whatever means you then need to convert the value again to NMEA format; that's not much of an issue, though:

```
printf("%l.%.5l", milliMinutes / 10000, milliMinutes % 10000);
```

Of course you can adjust this to other precisions as well ;)

Side note: All code entirely untested, if you find a bug, please fix yourself...